# Use Python to programmatically save PDFs, just like a PDF reader

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-form

I have a PDF template that I pre-populate with Python. I tried using PyPDF2, pdfrw and now I am using fillpdf because it's the simplest to use and produces the same results.

My problem is that all the PDFs pre-populated with Python are not being accepted by e-signature providers like DocuSign and OneSpan...

I found this solution:
https://www.valleycollege.edu/about-sbvc/offices/campus-technology-services/documents/blank_pdf_issue.pdf

But that requires that I open the file manually and print as PDF. Is there a way to do this automatically with Python? Is there another solution?

```
from fillpdf.fillpdfs import write_fillable_pdf    
data = {
        "Name": "Value1",
    }
    input_pdf_file = "input.pdf"
    output_pdf_file = "filled.pdf"

    write_fillable_pdf(input_pdf_file, output_pdf_file, data, flatten=True)
```

Comment: I tried that library, I keep getting: subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'pdftk input.pdf fill_form C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpd4cwo8pp output f.pdf flatten' returned non-zero exit status 1.

My code: pypdftk.fill_form(input_pdf_file, data, 'f.pdf', flatten=True)